# telnet from java

Tags: java, linux, telnet

I am trying to connect to remote linux system from another linux system through telnet using java code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  /usr/bin/telnet
    try
    {
        String line, commandInput;
        ProcessBuilder telnetProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");
        telnetProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process telnetProcess = telnetProcessBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(telnetProcess.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(telnetProcess.getOutputStream()));
        commandInput = "telnet <hostname> -l <username>\n";
        output.write(commandInput);
        output.flush();
        commandInput = "<password>\n";
        output.write(commandInput);
        output.flush();
        commandInput = "ls -l\n";
        output.write(commandInput);
        output.flush();
        commandInput = "pwd\n";
        output.write(commandInput);
        output.flush();
        commandInput = "exit\n";
        output.write(commandInput);
        output.flush();
        commandInput = "uname -a\n";
        output.write(commandInput);
        output.flush();
        commandInput = "exit\n";
        output.write(commandInput);
        output.flush();
        while((line = input.readLine())!= null)
            System.out.println(line);
        //telnetProcess.destroy();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am able to connect to remote machine and execute the commands before first exit and it logout from remote machine when first exit comes. Now, the problem is i am not able to execute commands after 1st exit even if its exit command from /bin/bash, which will finish the process execution with code 0. And if i destroy the process after 1st exit the BufferedReader and BufferedWriter won't work which generally works if process exits with code 0. I am not sure what can cause this the non-execution of commands after 1st exit. Please let me know the answer if anybody already faced it sometime.

Thanks

Ashutosh

Answer (score 1):

Read [When `Runtime.exec()` won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), it has **tons** of good advice when calling external executables.

A pretty likely problem with your code is that you don't read `stdout` of the process until the end of your code. This can **easily** lead to a point where the output buffer of the process is full and it can't do any more output until you've read some.

You **must** read the output of the process on a separate thread (see the article for details *and* code).

Comment: Hi Joachim, thanks for answer. As you told i changed a code a bit and instead of telnet and its password, i just gave normal commands to /bin/bash, 10 normal commands like pwd, uname -a, whoami, finger<username>, cat <file-name>of almost 100kb of text and did "ls /etc/init.d -l\n" command almost 10 times which is pretty big in my linux system and finally gave exit command and program worked flawlessly with all output printed on console window and exited with code 0. But, i have this issue after what i questioned about. Thanks anyway for ur quick reply.